# Long compile time when using a function (Swift 4)

Tags: swift, functional-programming, lazy-evaluation, type-inference, swift4

The following code compiles within reasonable time on its own<sup>[EXAMPLE](http://swift.sandbox.bluemix.net/#/repl/599450f4af2e7a5d0b0e19e9)</sup>:

```
public struct LazyProduct6Sequence <
  T1: LazySequenceProtocol, T2: LazySequenceProtocol, T3: LazySequenceProtocol,
  T4: LazySequenceProtocol, T5: LazySequenceProtocol, T6: LazySequenceProtocol
>: LazySequenceProtocol {
  public typealias Element = (T1.Element, T2.Element, T3.Element, T4.Element, T5.Element, T6.Element)
  public typealias Iterator = AnyIterator<Element>

  private let iterator: Iterator

  internal init (
    _ sequence1: T1, _ sequence2: T2, _ sequence3: T3,
    _ sequence4: T4, _ sequence5: T5, _ sequence6: T6
  ) {
    self.iterator = AnyIterator(
      sequence1.flatMap { element1 in
        sequence2.flatMap { element2 in
          sequence3.flatMap { element3 in
            sequence4.flatMap { element4 in
              sequence5.flatMap { element5 in
                sequence6.map { element6 in
                  (element1, element2, element3, element4, element5, element6)
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }.makeIterator()
    )
  }

  public func makeIterator () -> Iterator {
    return self.iterator
  }
}

public func product <
  T1: LazySequenceProtocol, T2: LazySequenceProtocol, T3: LazySequenceProtocol,
  T4: LazySequenceProtocol, T5: LazySequenceProtocol, T6: LazySequenceProtocol
> (
  _ sequence1: T1, _ sequence2: T2, _ sequence3: T3,
  _ sequence4: T4, _ sequence5: T5, _ sequence6: T6
) -> LazyProduct6Sequence<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6> {
  return LazyProduct6Sequence(sequence1, sequence2, sequence3, sequence4, sequence5, sequence6)
}
```

However, when compiling code that uses it, it takes about 40 seconds to compile (or refuses to compile at all)<sup>[EXAMPLE](http://swift.sandbox.bluemix.net/#/repl/59945164af2e7a5d0b0e19ea)</sup>:

```
_ = product([1, 2].lazy, [3, 4].lazy, [5, 6].lazy, [7, 8].lazy, [9, 10].lazy, [11, 12].lazy)
```

**Why does it take such a huge amount of time to compile?**

Comment: Long compile times usually have to do with type inference complexity. Try annotating the types of the closure parameters `{ (element1: T1.Element) in` for every closure.

Comment: @AllenHumphreys: It definitely has to do with type inference, yes. Adding explicit return types to each closure didn't help very much as the compile time stayed pretty much the same. But compilation time is near instantaneous when I add an explicit type to the assignment that uses the function ([example](http://swift.sandbox.bluemix.net/#/repl/599487dcaf2e7a5d0b0e19fb)).

Comment: That's a pretty painful statement to have to write, but I'm not sure where there is room for improvement in the provided example. Type inference is always the thing causing compilation time problems with Swift, unfortunately. I'm not sure how it is with other languages that have strong types and inference, but I'd imagine that it's similar?

Comment: @AllenHumphreys: I'm still trying to figure out the best approach to writing lazy functions, so it might be that there is a better way that doesn't have this problem. But I think this has to be a bug of some sort. I'll file a bug report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can gether this has to do with Swift's type inference system. Adding explicit return types to each closure didn't help very much as the compile times stayed pretty much the same. But compilation is near instantaneous when I add an explicit type to the assignment that uses the function<sup>[EXAMPLE](https://swift.sandbox.bluemix.net/#/repl/599487dcaf2e7a5d0b0e19fb)</sup>:

```
let sequence: LazyProduct6Sequence<
  LazyRandomAccessCollection<[Int]>,
  LazyRandomAccessCollection<[Int]>,
  LazyRandomAccessCollection<[Int]>,
  LazyRandomAccessCollection<[Int]>,
  LazyRandomAccessCollection<[Int]>,
  LazyRandomAccessCollection<[Int]>
> = product(
  [1, 2].lazy,
  [3, 4].lazy,
  [5, 6].lazy,
  [7, 8].lazy,
  [9, 10].lazy,
  [11, 12].lazy
)
let iterator = sequence.makeIterator()

while let element = iterator.next() {
  print(element)
}
```

Obviously this isn't ideal and is fugly.

I have no idea why it happens, since there is only one function that matches the expression.

It might be worth mentioning that for lower arities, the compilation time goes down. If I overload `product` to also take eager `Sequence`s then compiling will freeze my machine.

**EDIT**: I've since then figured out that these type of `Sequence`s should be lazy by default. Reworking my function using the same naming convention as Swift's `zip` the above example becomes:

```
public struct Product6Iterator <Sequence1: Sequence, Sequence2: Sequence, Sequence3: Sequence, Sequence4: Sequence,
    Sequence5: Sequence, Sequence6: Sequence>: IteratorProtocol {
  public typealias Element = (Sequence1.Element, Sequence2.Element, Sequence3.Element, Sequence4.Element,
    Sequence5.Element, Sequence6.Element)

  private let iterator: AnyIterator<Element>

  internal init (_ sequence1: Sequence1, _ sequence2: Sequence2, _ sequence3: Sequence3, _ sequence4: Sequence4,
      _ sequence5: Sequence5, _ sequence6: Sequence6) {
    self.iterator = AnyIterator(
      sequence1.lazy.flatMap { element1 in
        sequence2.lazy.flatMap { element2 in
          sequence3.lazy.flatMap { element3 in
            sequence4.lazy.flatMap { element4 in
              sequence5.lazy.flatMap { element5 in
                sequence6.lazy.map { element6 in
                  (element1, element2, element3, element4, element5, element6)
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }.makeIterator()
    )
  }

  public mutating func next () -> Element? {
    return self.iterator.next()
  }
}

public struct Product6Sequence <Sequence1: Sequence, Sequence2: Sequence, Sequence3: Sequence, Sequence4: Sequence,
    Sequence5: Sequence, Sequence6: Sequence>: Sequence {
  public typealias Iterator = Product6Iterator<Sequence1, Sequence2, Sequence3, Sequence4, Sequence5, Sequence6>
  public typealias Element = Iterator.Element

  private let sequence1: Sequence1
  private let sequence2: Sequence2
  private let sequence3: Sequence3
  private let sequence4: Sequence4
  private let sequence5: Sequence5
  private let sequence6: Sequence6

  internal init (_ sequence1: Sequence1, _ sequence2: Sequence2, _ sequence3: Sequence3, _ sequence4: Sequence4,
      _ sequence5: Sequence5, _ sequence6: Sequence6) {
    self.sequence1 = sequence1
    self.sequence2 = sequence2
    self.sequence3 = sequence3
    self.sequence4 = sequence4
    self.sequence5 = sequence5
    self.sequence6 = sequence6
  }

  public func makeIterator () -> Iterator {
    return Iterator(sequence1, sequence2, sequence3, sequence4, sequence5, sequence6)
  }
}

public func product <Sequence1: Sequence, Sequence2: Sequence, Sequence3: Sequence, Sequence4: Sequence,
    Sequence5: Sequence, Sequence6: Sequence> (_ sequence1: Sequence1, _ sequence2: Sequence2, _ sequence3: Sequence3,
    _ sequence4: Sequence4, _ sequence5: Sequence5, _ sequence6: Sequence6) -> Product6Sequence<Sequence1, Sequence2,
    Sequence3, Sequence4, Sequence5, Sequence6> {
  return sequence1.product(sequence2, sequence3, sequence4, sequence5, sequence6)
}

public extension Sequence {
  func product <Sequence2: Sequence, Sequence3: Sequence, Sequence4: Sequence, Sequence5: Sequence,
      Sequence6: Sequence> (_ sequence2: Sequence2, _ sequence3: Sequence3, _ sequence4: Sequence4,
      _ sequence5: Sequence5, _ sequence6: Sequence6) -> Product6Sequence<Self, Sequence2, Sequence3, Sequence4,
      Sequence5, Sequence6> {
    return Product6Sequence(self, sequence2, sequence3, sequence4, sequence5, sequence6)
  }
}
```

This, along with other similar `Sequence` extensions, can be found in a library I've created called [SequenceExtensions](https://github.com/dennisvennink/SequenceExtensions).